# LINQ to SQL - running total

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sql-to-linq-conversion

I am trying to get a running total on an SQL table using Entity Framework. My raw SQL query looks like this:

```
select *, sum(Amount) over(order by Date, TransactionId) as RunningTotal
from Transactions
order by Date
```

But I can't figure out how to translate this into a LINQ query. Maybe it can't be done, since the sum() over() syntax was only introduced in SQL server 2012.

Comment: There is not even a linq-to-objects equivalent, let alone an EF equivalent (which in fact is a subset of L2O). Mocking `Partition by` would be possible with a `let` clause and a subquery, but a running total requires sequential processing, which is always hard with LINQ. I think the closest you can get is mocking a `partition by` followed by a classic `foreach` tallying the partition sums. It depends on the use case. A raw SQL query might be the best option.

Comment: Yeah, I think a raw query may the only way to go about it. I wanted the entities returned to be tracked by EF, but I'll just do a separate query to get the running total since it can't be edited or changed anyway.